# Handling CDATA and Comment in ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree

Is there a way to get `ElementTree.parse` to take `CDATA` tags and/or comments into consideration?

Answer (score 5):

[lxml](http://lxml.de/), which can act as a [drop-in replacement](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) for the standard library `ElementTree`,  has support for [CDATA](http://lxml.de/api.html#cdata).